# Memory increases when merging multiple high resolution images into single image, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have to merge multiple images in to single (all of high resolution), It acquires lots of memory. I saved original images to local directory and set resized images to imageviews, placed on different locations on main image. Now at the time of saving final merged image, I then read the original images from local directory. here the memory increases, that cause error (crash due to memory) for higher number of images.

here is code: retrieving original image from local directory

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self getOriginalImagePath:imageview.tag]];
```

Is there any other way to get images from local directory without loading it into memory.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show a bit more code on what you proceed to do with the images, e.g., are you unnecessarily keeping multiple original images in memory after resizing?

Comment: Here is code: resized image and simply assigned to imageview. Then i perform scaling and rotation on imageview. 
UIImage *pThumbsImage = [self scaleImageToSize:CGSizeMake(AppScreenBound.size.width, AppScreenBound.size.height) imageWithImage:pOrignalImage];

[imageView setImage:pThumbImage];

everything is okay here. the problem occurs while saving it or generating merged image. 

Thanks Arkku

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to load an image without it going into memory. With some image formats you could, in theory, implement your own reader that scales the image down while reading the file, so that the original size never ends up in memory, but that would require a lot of work for little gain.

Overall you would be better off just saving the different sizes of images as separate files and loading only the correct size (you seem to be scaling them based on the screen size, so there are not that many different versions required).

If you do keep to resizing them on the fly, try to ensure that you get rid of the original versions as soon as possible, i.e., don't keep any image reference no longer required, and perhaps wrap the whole thing in `@autoreleasepool` (assuming ARC is being used):

```
@autoreleasepool {
    UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self getOriginalImagePath:imageview.tag]];
    UIImage *pThumbsImage = [self scaleImageToSize:CGSizeMake(AppScreenBound.size.width, AppScreenBound.size.height) imageWithImage:pOrignalImage];
    originalImage = nil;
    imageView.image = pThumbImage;
    pThumbImage = nil;
    // … ?
}
```

Similarly treat any other image handling that creates intermediate versions, i.e., get rid of references no longer required as soon as possible (such as by assigning `nil` or having them fall out of scope), and put `@autoreleasepool { … }` around subsections that may generate temporary objects.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, posting it as an answer to my own question, might help other people. reference from [Image I/O Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_source/ikpg_source.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH218-SW3)

An alternative to "imageWithContentsOfFile:", one can use ***an Image Source***

here is a code how I use it.

```
UIImage *originalWMImage = [self createCGImageFromFile:your-image-path];
```

the method createCGImageFromFile: get an image content without loading it to memory

```
-(UIImage*) createCGImageFromFile :(NSString*)path
{
    // Get the URL for the pathname passed to the function.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    CGImageRef        myImage = NULL;
    CGImageSourceRef  myImageSource;
    CFDictionaryRef   myOptions = NULL;
    CFStringRef       myKeys[2];
    CFTypeRef         myValues[2];

    // Set up options if you want them. The options here are for
    // caching the image in a decoded form and for using floating-point
    // values if the image format supports them.
    myKeys[0] = kCGImageSourceShouldCache;
    myValues[0] = (CFTypeRef)kCFBooleanTrue;
    myKeys[1] = kCGImageSourceShouldAllowFloat;
    myValues[1] = (CFTypeRef)kCFBooleanTrue;

    // Create the dictionary
    myOptions = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **) myKeys,
                                   (const void **) myValues, 2,
                                   &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                   & kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    // Create an image source from the URL.
    myImageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)url, myOptions);
    CFRelease(myOptions);

    // Make sure the image source exists before continuing
    if (myImageSource == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Image source is NULL.");
        return  NULL;
    }

    // Create an image from the first item in the image source.
    myImage = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(myImageSource,
                                              0,
                                              NULL);

    CFRelease(myImageSource);

    // Make sure the image exists before continuing
    if (myImage == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Image not created from image source.");
        return NULL;
    }

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:myImage];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code: resized image and simply assigned to imageview. Then i perform scaling and rotation on imageview.

```
UIImage *pThumbsImage = [self scaleImageToSize:CGSizeMake(AppScreenBound.size.width, AppScreenBound.size.height) imageWithImage:pOrignalImage]; 
    [imageView setImage:pThumbImage];
```

here when saving:this code is within for loop: (upto number of images to merge on main image)

```
// get size of the second image
    CGFloat backgroundWidth = canvasSize.width;
    CGFloat backgroundHeight = canvasSize.height;

    //Image View: to be merged
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:stampImage];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, stampFrameSize.size.width , stampFrameSize.size.height)];

    // Rotate Image View
    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = imageView.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform, radian);
    [imageView setTransform:newTransform];

    // Scale Image View
    CGRect imageFrame = [imageView frame];

    // Create Final Stamp View
    UIView  *finalStamp = nil;
    finalStamp = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageFrame.size.width, imageFrame.size.height)];

    // Set Center of Stamp Image
    [imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(imageFrame.size.width /2, imageFrame.size.height /2)];
    [finalImageView addSubview:imageView];

    // Create Image From image View;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(finalStamp.frame.size);
    [finalStamp.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImage *pfinalMainImage = nil;

    // Create Final Image With Stamp
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(backgroundWidth, backgroundHeight));
    [canvasImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundWidth, backgroundHeight)];
    [viewImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(stampFrameSize.origin.x , stampFrameSize.origin.y , stampImageFrame.size.width  , stampImageFrame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:fAlphaValue];
    pfinalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

everything is okay here. the problem occurs while saving it or generating merged image.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I had to face something like that recently... so there is my answer.

I had to merge a lot of images into one, and had the same problem. The memory increased until the app crashes. The functions that I created, returned UIImage and that was the problem. The ARC was not releasing at time, so I had to change to return CGImageRef and release them at properly time.